# Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.maven.wrapper.MavenWrapperMain

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

I cloned this project in my system:

https://github.com/dmikusa-pivotal/zuul-proxy-uaa

As per readme, I ran the command:  `./mvnw spring-boot:run`

and get the following errr:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.maven.wrapper.MavenWrapperMain
```

What could I be missing? Or there is something broken/missing in the project itself?

Answer (score 0):

To make the Maven's wrapper work you need:

1. The environment variable `JAVA_HOME` pointing to a valid JDK.
2. The `.mvn` directory containing the wrapper's binary files.

The project you pointed out is missing the `.mvn` directory, that's why you get the error.

To get the missing files, I suggest to go to [Spring Initializr](https://start.spring.io/), make a project then copy the `.mvn` directory in the root of `zuul-proxy-uaa` project. (You can also copy the mvnw files and overwrite the existent ones, to be sure it's working properly)

Answer (score -2):

You can download and install maven on your PC. Then run `mvn spring-boot:run` from project directory.